# bash on Windows は posix 互換ですか？

Tags: windows, windows-10, posix, wsl

Windows10 になって、 Windows でも bash が使えるようになったと聞きました。

この bash (から実行できる環境)は、 posix 互換ですか？ posix 互換のスクリプト、プログラムならばすべて動かせるのか知りたいと思い質問しています。そうでないなら、具体的にどのような部分が互換でないのでしょうか。

(補足すると、msys とかは、 bash は利用できるけれども、posix ではないのでいろいろ苦労したりするので、今回の発表された bash はどうなのだろうと思い、質問しています)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

基本的にはWindowsカーネルのサブシステムでLinuxカーネルのシステムコールをサポートして本物のUbuntu x86_64ユーザーランドを動かす仕組みですが、すべてのLinux/POSIXシステムコールにはまだ対応していないようです。たとえば、UNIXドメインソケットなどにも未対応だったはず。